# Get the first Monday in the month

Tags: ios, nsdate

I would like to test if today is the first Monday of the month. I am doing like this :

```
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSInteger weekdayOfDate = [gregorianCalendar ordinalityOfUnit:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit forDate:today];

 if (weekdayOfDate == 2) 
 {   
     // Monday 
 }
```

But this code is correct for every monday in the month. How i can get just the first Monday of the month ?

Comment: And day of month <= 7?

Comment: Thanks. I think it's the correct answer. I will accept your answer if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a condition checking if we're currently in the first 7 days of the month. However, also notice that some of the values you're using have been deprecated, starting from iOS8. I've added the complete version of the code, including replacements for the deprecated values:

```
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSInteger weekdayOfDate = [gregorianCalendar ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekday inUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear forDate:today];
NSInteger dayOfMonth = [gregorianCalendar ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay inUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth forDate:today];

if (weekdayOfDate == 2 && dayOfMonth <= 7)
{
    // This is the first Monday of this month
}
```